# Equivalent Definitions of Divergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the equivalence of two definitions of diverging ($+ \infty$).

The first definition, which I asked a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587819/definition-of-divergence-negation-rules) about, was purely negating the definition of a series converging.

> $\forall A \in \mathbb R$, $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb N$, $\exists n > N$ such that $|A - a_n| \geq \epsilon$

Just for completeness I will include my definition of convergence:

> Given a sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ we say that it converges if $\exists A \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $|A - a_n| < \epsilon$.

The definition my professor appears to be using is:

> For all $M > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $a_n > M$.

My question is, how do justify that definition of divergence from the definition we have of convergence? Intuitively it makes sense, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how it is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT a definition of divergence. For example take $a_n=(-1)^n$ to have a sequence which is not convergent but does not fulfil your condition.
But IF a sequence fulfils it, THAN it has to be divergent.

Comment: I found http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Divergent_To_Infinity which appear to be the same definition (If you are referring to the second definition).

Comment: Well, usually you define "divergent" as "not convergent". "divergence to infinity" is just one special case of divergence and does not cover all divergent sequences.

Comment: Ah I was using _divergent_ and _not convergent_ interchangeably. So both of my definitions are actually the definition of not converging rather than diverging?

Comment: "divergent" and "not convergent" IS interchangeably. The first definition of "divergent" is the negation of you definition of "convergent", exactly as you mentioned. --- but the condition your question was about, holds just for a special type of divergent sequences: Those which tend to infinitiy. In other words: you cannot take this as a definition of "divergent".

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.